# Date field prevents synchronization in cloud kit

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

I created a "big" database in Cloud Kit. Syncing works so far.
But in one Entity, there's a incomprehensible error / problem:

When I use an attribute of an Entity of type "Date", synchronization suddenly stops. I have no idea, why. It took me three months to figure out that the date field was the reason the sync stopped working.

Example:

Entity: "Report"

Attributes:

- id: UUID
- klient: UUID
- changes: String
- reportAt: Date

When deleting report-attribute, everything works fine. Adding report again, syncing stops again. Does anybody know about this problem or does anybody know a solution for this? Is there a limitation on date-fields? (Doesn't make sense, but..)

I use date-attributes in many other tables (Entities) and they all work fine. But suddenly, in this Entity (and I can delete it, create another one, rename it, create a different one with same oder different name) everything breaks.

Update:
the field itself is not the problem, I think. But storing a date to this attribute will cause a syncing-crash. As long as I leave this field empty and I store nil, everything works fine.

The code for my date-picker-field ist the same, I use everywhere in my app and there's no problem at all, only on this Entity.

```
HStack {
    Label("Berichtsdatum", systemImage: "bolt.fill")
        .labelStyle(.titleOnly)
        .frame(width: AppSettings.labelWidth, alignment: .leading)
        .font(.callout)
    Spacer()
    if reportAt != nil {
        DatePicker(selection: Binding<Date>(
            get: {self.reportAt ?? Date()},
            set: {self.reportAt = $0}
        ), displayedComponents: [.date], label: { Text("Letzter Kontakt") })
        .padding(.leading, 0.0)
        .frame(width: AppSettings.fieldWidthDate)
        .labelsHidden()
    }
    Toggle("Herausgabe am Bool",
           isOn: Binding(isNotNil: $reportAt, defaultValue: Date())
    ).labelsHidden()
}
```